# PHP convertor Html(css) to Pdf?

Tags: php, html-to-pdf

**Duplicate:** [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I am looking php based library for HTML->PDF convertor, for report generation in my application. By far I found [one](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), and it seems good, but has some limitations. 
Can anyone suggest any other advanced ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be answered by **[this previously-posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php)**.  However, you may also want to take a look at [HTML2PDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf), or any of the variety of PHP PDF libraries that can be found with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I used `html2ps` and then `ghostscript` to convert html pages to pdf, because it gave better results, then all html2pdf libraries.

But the may have changed in the time. The best is to try some libraries, because the quality of the generated pdf's also depends on the style of html you are using as base.

Answer (score 0):

If using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) there is a script which extends that class to do some basic HTML formatting (not CSS though).  Available here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php